# unique multidimensional array based on specific multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array which I need to be sorted with unique array based on specific keys. There are same values on `item_type_id` keys with different `partner_id` and `store_id` keys. The result that I expect is when the `item_type_id` keys have same value and in different `partner_id` keys with same `store_id`, it should prefer `10017` value first on `partner_id` keys.

**Example array**

```
[
    0 => [
        "partner_id" => "10017"
        "store_id" => "1000"
        "item_type_id" => "2"
        "value" => "58"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    1 => [
        "partner_id" => "10017"
        "store_id" => "1000"
        "item_type_id" => "1"
        "value" => "63"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    2 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1000"
        "item_type_id" => "3"
        "value" => "29"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    3 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1000"
        "item_type_id" => "2"
        "value" => "58"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    4 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1001"
        "item_type_id" => "1"
        "value" => "65"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    5 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1001"
        "item_type_id" => "2"
        "value" => "58"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    6 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1001"
        "item_type_id" => "3"
        "value" => "29"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
    7 => [
        "partner_id" => "0"
        "store_id" => "1000"
        "item_type_id" => "1"
        "value" => "65"
        "category" => "1"
    ]
]
```

**Results**

```
[
    1000 => [
        0 => [
            "partner_id" => "10017"
            "store_id" => "1000"
            "item_type_id" => "2"
            "value" => "58"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
        1 => [
            "partner_id" => "10017"
            "store_id" => "1000"
            "item_type_id" => "1"
            "value" => "63"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
        2 => [
            "partner_id" => "0"
            "store_id" => "1000"
            "item_type_id" => "3"
            "value" => "29"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
    ]

    1001 => [
        0 => [
            "partner_id" => "0"
            "store_id" => "1001"
            "item_type_id" => "1"
            "value" => "65"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
        1 => [
            "partner_id" => "0"
            "store_id" => "1001"
            "item_type_id" => "2"
            "value" => "58"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
        2 => [
            "partner_id" => "0"
            "store_id" => "1001"
            "item_type_id" => "3"
            "value" => "29"
            "category" => "1"
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Here is my script**

```
$storeID = [1000,1001];
$createdArray = [];
$previous_item_type_id = "";
$previous_partner_id = "";
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($storeID); $i++) {
        if($array["store_id"] == $storeID[$i]) {
            if($array["item_type_id"] != $previous_item_type_id && $array["partner_id"] != $previous_partner_id) {
                $createdArray[$storeID[$i]] = [
                        "partner_id" => $array["partner_id"],
                        "store_id" => $array["store_id"],
                        "item_type_id" => $array["item_type_id"],
                        "value" => $array["value"],
                        "category" => $array["category"],
                    ];
            } else {
                $previous_item_type_id = $array["item_type_id"];
                $previous_partner_id = $array["partner_id"];
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
}

dd($createdArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple foreach loop to iterate through your array, then use the sub array key `store_id` to get the key of the final array. push in that final array the value of the current value.

Plus, to remove the duplicated `item_type_id`, I would write a function that checks if that id already exists in the result.

In example :

```
$storeID = [1000,1001];

$array = [
    0 => [
        "partner_id" => "10017",
        "store_id" => "1000",
        "item_type_id" => "2",
        "value" => "58",
        "category" => "1"
    ],
    1 => [
        "partner_id" => "10017",
        "store_id" => "1000",
        "item_type_id" => "1",
        "value" => "63",
        "category" => "1",
    ],
    2 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1000",
        "item_type_id" => "3",
        "value" => "29",
        "category" => "1"
    ],
    3 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1000",
        "item_type_id" => "2",
        "value" => "58",
        "category" => "1",
    ],
    4 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1001",
        "item_type_id" => "1",
        "value" => "65",
        "category" => "1",
    ],
    5 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1001",
        "item_type_id" => "2",
        "value" => "58",
        "category" => "1",
    ],
    6 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1001",
        "item_type_id" => "3",
        "value" => "29",
        "category" => "1"
    ],
    7 => [
        "partner_id" => "0",
        "store_id" => "1000",
        "item_type_id" => "1",
        "value" => "65",
        "category" => "1"
    ]
];

function ItemIdExists($arr, $itemId)
{
    foreach ($arr as $subValue)
    {
        if ($subValue["item_type_id"] == $itemId)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $key = $value["store_id"];
    if (in_array($key, $storeID))
    {
        $ItemIdFound = isset($result[$key]) && ItemIdExists($result[$key], $value["item_type_id"]);

        if (!$ItemIdFound)
            $result[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [1000]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(5) "10017"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1000"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "58"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(5) "10017"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1000"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "63"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1000"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "29"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  [1001]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1001"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "65"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1001"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "58"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["partner_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["store_id"]=>
      string(4) "1001"
      ["item_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "29"
      ["category"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: on your result, there is duplicate item_type_id on same store_id. you could see the result that i expected.

Comment: duplicate partner_id yes, but the store_id and item_type_id are different.

Comment: Ah you want to keep the distinct pair partner_id and item_type_id  ? editing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements, the desired result will:

- group on `store_id` values and
- when `item_type_id` values collide, the row with a non-zero `partner_id` value should overwrite a row with a zero `partner_id` value

Using temporary keys to construct a deeper lookup structure will allow greater efficiency that searching in a loop because key lookups with `isset()` will always outperform value lookups (with any technique -- even an early return).

After all of the grouping and filtering is done in the loop, flatten the data relating to each store into an associative array of indexed arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EN4dN))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row['partner_id'] || !isset($result[$row['store_id']][$row['item_type_id']])) {
        $result[$row['store_id']][$row['item_type_id']][$row['partner_id']] = $row;
    }
}

var_export(array_map(function($row) { return array_merge(...$row); }, $result));
```

The snippet above only adds a row into the restructured array if the `partner_id` is not zero or if the combination of `store_id`-`item_type_id`-`partner_id` has not been encountered before.